# Positioning one tikz with regard to another tikz nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two `tikzpicture` within a figure and I would like to place one tikz  relatively to the other tikz nodes. I tried `below of=` with no success. The two tikz have different arrows and layouts. Here is the code where I need to place the second tikz under the `ABC` node.

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
    \node (1){$ABC$};
    \node (2)[right of=1]{$CD$};
    \path (1) edge (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1cm,semithick,scale=-.2]

    \node (236) {$236$};
    \node (136) [below left of=236]{$136$};
    \node (246) [below of=236]{$246$};
    \node (235) [below right of=236]{$235$};

    \path (236) edge (136)  edge (246) edge(235);

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Example}
    \label{example}
    \end{figure}
```

How can I place the second tikz under the first one's ABC node?

Comment: instead of doing two `tikzpicture`s you should revert to one `tikzpicture` and two `scope`s which can be aligned accordingly. Much cleaner and much easier for TeX to align.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scopes are your friend here:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=4cm]
    \node (1){$ABC$};
    \node (2)[right of=1]{$CD$};
    \path (1) edge (2);
    \begin{scope} [below of = 1, yshift = 2.5cm, 
            ->,>=stealth,node distance=1cm,semithick,scale=-.2]
    \node (236) {$236$};
    \node (136) [below left of=236]{$136$};
    \node (246) [below of=236]{$246$};
    \node (235) [below right of=236]{$235$};
    \path (236) edge (136)  edge (246) edge(235);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: positioning using scope]

I included the `yshift` because it uses the outer `node distance` of 4cm, and it looked like too much space for my taste.  You can remove that or adjust as necessary.

Comment: nice so each scope can be viewed as a tikzpicture by its own.